# What are the criticisms of Jung?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, developmental-psychology, jung

Jungian psychology seems to have established itself in our culture (books and films draw on its archetypes etc) and, although I am by no means an expert, it seems analytical psychology is broadly considered to have some merit.

What are the main objections, criticisms, and refutations of Jung's ideas?

In particular, are there strong evidence-based contradictions of his ideas?